# Facebook Android Unity scores api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When i try submit scores from Android Unity game i receive next error:

```
You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
```

ava.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me/scores

```
FB.Login("publish_actions", OnLoginComplete);
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        query["score"] = "110";
        FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate(FBResult r) { Debug.Log("!!!! Score submit result: " + r.Text); }, query);
```

Facebook sdk version 5.1.0
Unity version 4.5.2f1

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the most common cause of this error is not having your app configured as a "Game" in the app settings on Facebook. OP and I talked elsewhere, earlier, and ruled that out in this case, but for anyone else finding this post via search, make sure you check that.

To clarify, the code starting with "`var query`" - is it possible that it is running before OnLoginComplete is called? If you've ruled that out, could you verify whether the problem might be with the grant of permissions? An easy way to do that would be to log the value of the access token right when you make the call to FB.API, then copy-paste that into the access token debugging tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and verify that it actually has publish_actions. You could also just take that token and use it in curl in verbose mode (`curl -kv "https://graph.facebook.com/me/scores?score=110&access_token=TOKEN"`), and see if the headers or response body gives any additional clues.